# Sitecore - Page search Vs Item search

Tags: lucene, web-crawler, sitecore

I am trying to do a website search for my application using sitecore. 
The challenge is  - While i can do that using Lucene - i am able to crawl the items and return the items but not the actual Page. The Page item could be very different from the actual content item.
While this looks like a very common use case, i am not able to find solution to achieve this. 
I did find tools like Coveo that can integrate with Sitecore and crawl the pages, but they dont provide complete APIs. 
Wanted to know the general approach on how people perceive this.

Comment: Is the primary content on the page coming from the page item itself?

Comment: Can you expand on which APIs are missing from Coveo please? I work for Coveo and I can route you to the API documentation you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what part of the API you are looking to use from Coveo, but I would usually recommend Coveo or Google Search when you want page-based searching.

One way to achieve this with Lucene/SOLR is to have specific search index with a computed field for the page content. Make sure that you only index items that are your page-type of templates in this index. Your computed field logic can then gather all the datasources on the page item and create a consolidated collection of all the text that can be used for your text searches.

Another alternative is to have the computed field contain the output HTML of the page. There's a github repo for this: https://github.com/hermanussen/sitecore-html-crawler

**Similar question:** [Components not indexed in sitecore lucene search indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343211/components-not-indexed-in-sitecore-lucene-search-indexes)